# Display div's on Menu item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a site which has only one page, instead of loading different pages for different bits of content; I want the content to change but not the page therefore decreasing loading and creating a nice effect.

As you can see from my code below it's long but it works, I am sure there is a much easier way to do it and animating between the divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssLY3/

HTML

```
<ul class="side-nav" id="sideNav">
  <li id="homeNav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li id="bioNav"><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
  <li id="musicNav"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
  <li id="photosNav"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
  <li id="shopNav"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="homePage">
  <p>HOME PAGE</p>
</div>
<div id="biogPage">
  <p>BIOG PAGE</p>
</div>
<div id="musicPage">
  <p>MUSIC PAGE</p>
</div>
<div id="photosPage">
  <p>PHOTOS PAGE</p>
</div>
<div id="shopPage">
  <p>SHOP PAGE</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#biogPage').hide();
$('#musicPage').hide();
$('#photosPage').hide();
$('#shopPage').hide();

$('#homeNav').click(function () {
  $('#homePage').show();
  $('#biogPage').hide();
  $('#musicPage').hide();
  $('#photosPage').hide();
  $('#shopPage').hide();
});

$('#bioNav').click(function () {
  $('#homePage').hide();
  $('#biogPage').show();
  $('#musicPage').hide();
  $('#photosPage').hide();
  $('#shopPage').hide();
});

$('#musicNav').click(function () {
  $('#homePage').hide();
  $('#biogPage').hide();
  $('#musicPage').show();
  $('#photosPage').hide();
  $('#shopPage').hide();
});

$('#photosNav').click(function () {
  $('#homePage').hide();
  $('#biogPage').hide();
  $('#musicPage').hide();
  $('#photosPage').show();
  $('#shopPage').hide();
});

$('#shopNav').click(function () {
  $('#homePage').hide();
  $('#biogPage').hide();
  $('#musicPage').hide();
  $('#photosPage').hide();
  $('#shopPage').show();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wrap all of your divs inside a parent div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="homePage"><p>HOME PAGE</p></div>
    <div id="biogPage"><p>BIOG PAGE</p></div>
    <div id="musicPage"><p>MUSIC PAGE</p></div>
    <div id="photosPage"><p>PHOTOS PAGE</p></div>
    <div id="shopPage"><p>SHOP PAGE</p></div>
</div>
```

Then you can take advantage of the index of your list to show according div element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#biogPage, #musicPage, #photosPage, #shopPage').hide();

    $(".side-nav li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $("#wrapper").find("div:eq('" + i + "')").show().siblings().hide();
        });
    }); 
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssLY3/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<a class="link" title="div1" href="#">link1</a>
<a class="link" title="div2" href="#">link2</a>
<a class="link" title="div3" href="#">link3</a>
<a class="link" title="div4" href="#">link4</a>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="div1" class="box">div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="box">div2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="box">div3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="box">div4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

- html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
  }
  .box {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  }

Minimized javascript

```
(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(e) {
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})();
```

i think this javascript is probably the most minimal one

check this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bqBaA/

vote up if u like this

Answer (score 0):

Another way that changes your HTML as little as possible:

HTML:

```
<ul class="side-nav" id="sideNav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home" class="page"><p>HOME PAGE</p></div>
<div id="blog" class="page"><p>BLOG PAGE</p></div>
<div id="music" class="page"><p>MUSIC PAGE</p></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hideall = function() {
        $(".page").each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    };
    hideall();

    $(".side-nav li a").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var ta = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            hideall();
            $("#"+ta).show();
        });
    });


});
```